# IMobileServiceSyncTable "Where" clause on multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm actually using Microsoft Azure EasyTables for my Xamarin Forms application.

I have two objects : "Center" and "City". A city can be owned by several centers, so I created a table called "CenterCity" with two fields "CenterID" and "CityID".

In my data service object I created a IMobileServiceSyncTable per object type.
So I have three table objects:

- IMobileServiceSyncTable<CenterCity>
- IMobileServiceSyncTable<Center>
- IMobileServiceSyncTable<City>

My goal is to retrieve all the cities owned by one center.
How to achieve that ?
Here is the code I actually use, but I'm sure it's not the right one as it use several ReadAsync.

```
var l_arcResult = new List<City>();

var l_qCenterCities = m_msstCenterCities.Where(X => X.CenterID == p_strCenterGespotID);

foreach(var l_ccCurrent in await m_msstCenterCities.ReadAsync(l_qCenterCities))
{
  var l_qCity = m_msstCities.Where(X => X.GespotID == l_ccCurrent.CityID);

  foreach(var l_cCurrent in await m_msstCities.ReadAsync(l_qCity))
    l_arcResult.Add(l_cCurrent);
}

return (new List<City>());
```

Thank you advance for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have two objects : "Center" and "City". A city can be owned by several centers, so I created a table called "CenterCity" with two fields "CenterID" and "CityID".

Per my understanding, you are handling a Many:Many relationship between **Center** and **City**.

> My goal is to retrieve all the cities owned by one center.
>   How to achieve that ?

For retrieving all cities under a specific center, your code looks good. Moreover, you could also use the following code snippet:

```
var l_arcResult = new List<City>();
var cityIds=await m_msstCenterCities
       .Where(X => X.CenterID == p_strCenterGespotID)
       .Select(x=>x.CityID)
       .ToListAsync();
var cities=await m_msstCities.Where(X => cityIds.Contains(X.GespotID)).ToListAsync();
if(cities!=null)
    l_arcResult.AddRange(cities);
```

Moreover, you could follow adrian hall's book about [The Mobile Client](https://adrianhall.gitlab.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/).

---

**UPDATE:**

AFAIK, you could not only use a single code line to meet your requirement when using the mobile client SDK. Or you could directly use other 3rd libs to execute a single SQL statement as follows:

```html
select c.*
from CenterCity cc
left join City c on cc.CityId == c.id
where cc.CenterId = '{center-id}'
```

Comment: Hello Bruce,
Thank you very much for the answer.
I though that it was possible to achieve this in within only one sentence. But the trick in your code snippet is the use of "cityIds.Contains(...)".
And you are right I have Many:Many relationship between Center and City.

Comment: I updated my answer with some researches, you could refer to the updated part.